# How generate new project with routing module in angular using CLI command

Tags: angular-cli, angular-routing, angular-router

I want to create an Angular new project that contains app routing module using Cli command

Comment: This information can easily be found in the docs: https://angular.io/cli/new

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
ng new your-application-name --routing
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also add the style option (css or scss or less) on the same command :

```
ng new [app name here] --routing --style=scss
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use --routing param like:

```
ng new ng-app --routing
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by running a simple `ng new [app name here] --routing`.
the routing module will be added by the cli as part of the app creation